# Get current and previous month column with INDEX and MATCH

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a column and a row with `Index-Match`. The catch is that the column consists of dates and I would like to extract the current month, month - 2 of  the current month.

I tried the following:

```
=Index($B$6:$Y$13;MATCH(A17;$A$6:$A$13;0);MATCH(B1;FILTER($B$5:$Y$5;$B$5:$Y$5<=$B$1);0))
```

[image]

I still get `#N/A`.

Here is an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xp05kTCP8MJG4NAPJl1lKw6z4NzOQZJydqe1zYXSzoc/edit#gid=28723065).

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula seems right. The problem is it's looking for an exact date match. Currently, it's trying to match today's date (22nd) while all your dates in row 5 are on the 1st.

`=DATEVALUE("01."&MONTH(TODAY())&".2016")`

You could use a formula like that to get today's month and set it as a date value that parallels the structure you have in row 5. It seems to work month but you'd need a bit more work to get years to play nicely. You can see it pulling from [cell D2 here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15y7JYSsyfQEDspaajB5cDygHSuUmAP1FMRJUZbg8tTE/edit#gid=28723065).